# Adding keyboard shortcuts in applet

Tags: java, applet

How can I add keyboard shortcuts to a Java applet?

I had an assignment (I am taking Honors Computer Science) to make my name spin in a circle.
I used an infinite loop, and every time I want to end, I have to go to Task Manager and end the program. Can I add a shortcut that quits the applet?

For example, if I press the space bar, it will change to another part of the program.

I looked over ["How to Use Key Bindings"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) at Oracle's website but I could not understand it.

Comment: *"I have to go to Task Manager and end the program. Can I add a shortcut that quits the applet?"* Put a toggle button to the NORTH of it for Stop/Start.  BTW - just about everything that can be done in an app. can be done in an applet, though this situation is a little more tricky due to focus (the applet might not have input focus and is probably marked as not focusable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Swing (if you are creating a JApplet), then yes, Key Bindings are the way to go. What about them confuses you?

By the way, I know that this isn't directly related to your question, but if your applet is a Swing JApplet, I wouldn't use an infinite loop to do the animation, but rather I'd use a Swing Timer. If you use an infinite loop, you must take care to a) do the infinite loop in a background thread, and b) make most Swing calls from within the loop on the Swing event dispatch thread (or EDT) else you risk freezing the main Swing thread. A Swing Timer does all of this for you, and is thus much easier to use.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't understand how to add the key bindings to the program. Can you give me an example of what I would have to add to the coding to get the key bindings?

Comment: @the_pwner224: Google for the Key Bindings tutorial as it will show you all you need to know. If you get stuck, then come on back.

Comment: @the_pwner224: edit: I now remember that you already have the link, but all you say is  that you don't understand, but give no specifics. Without a specific question, there's no way we can help you other than to suggest that you re-read the tutorial. Consider asking a better more specific question.

Comment: I understand that there must be an input map and an action, but I do not understand what I have to add to my program to make it work. For example, this is my program: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54321609/folder/circlenameinf.java. I know I would have to add `component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),"doSomething");` and
`component.getActionMap().put("doSomething",anAction);` to detect when space was pressed and then to run 'anAction', but how would I create an action that runs the method 'stop' (at the bottom of my program)?

Comment: @the_pwner: Your code is not compilable or runnable for me. Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) here in the forum. Also, in your small runnable sscce, show the code where you try to use key bindings.

Answer (score 1):

All that tutorial is saying that you need a `KeyStroke`, some key `Object`, and an `Action` to create a key binding.

To create your `KeyStroke`, take a look at the static [helper methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28char%29), they should explain how to get the correct `KeyStroke` you need.

You can use any old `Object` as the key (`Object key = new Object()`).

The last thing you need is to create your `Action`. I would suggest extending [`AbstractAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) since it already implements many of the methods of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) for you.

To put your key binding together do the following:

```
JComponent c = ...
KeyStroke keyStroke = ...
Object key = ...
Action a = ...

c.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, key);
c.getActionMap().put(key, a);
```

Comment: Take a look at [Hovercraft Full of Eels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8935481/758280) answer, you should consider using a Swing Timer.

Comment: One frequent point of confusion is use of the `getInputMap(int condition)` override. Sometimes it takes some experimenting to use the right condition, which I think in the original poster's case will likely be `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. The tutorial explains quite a bit of this. 1+ vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oops, forgot to mention that.